# Magento 2 CatalogSearch cant get category by cat=id

Tags: magento, search, categories, catalog

Magento 2 CatalogSearch cant get category by cat=id
. 
I have 20 categories, but i can't to see it on site, just root category.

It is working on demo site: http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/catalogsearch/result/?q=blue&cat=2

PS: I have read it and try: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154287/magento-2-navigation-menu-not-showing

UPD: For any values ​​of "id" except = 1, writes "default" instead of the name of the category, if 1 then "root".

[For any values ​​of "id" except = 1, writes "default"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9x8P.png)

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put yours categories to default category.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18854084)

Comment: No, my post it`s answer, I have the same problem. In details Admin->Products->Categories, In the category tree, highlight yours and transfer to default category.